# how can I freeze a thread in Android Studio

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio

Back when I was using Eclipse for Android development, it was possible to select a thread and freeze it - so it would not run.  This allowed the debugging of one thread without interruptions from other threads.

How can a thread be frozen - prevented from running - in Android Studio.  I have found the list of threads but I do not see any controls for freezing a thread.

--------< additional information >----

2 people didn't understand the question, so let me try again.
In Eclipse, when debugging a multi-threaded app, you can suspend and resume threads in the debugger.

[image]

In the above image, you see the Debug view, showing a list of threads.  Right mouse on one of these threads and in the menu is Resume, Suspend, Terminate.  These menu actions apply to the selected thread.

When debugging multi-threaded apps, sometimes it is essential to suspend a thread temporarily.

In Android Studio, I can get a dump of the threads, and selecting each one shows me its stack trace on the right.

[image]

But I can not find any way to suspend and resume the thread.

Again this is a critical requirement of a debugger.

Does anyone know how this suspend/resume can be done in Android Studio???

Comment: Maybe `sleep` method?

Comment: In Java, there is no thread-safe way to forcibly terminate or interrupt a thread.  Thread interruption is a cooperative process.  The controlling thread may request termination or interruption in another thread (and there are mechanisms to help you do this), but the thread must also attend to its own termination/interruption when the request occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked under hood to be sure of this, but I imagine that it is using [JVMTI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/index.html).  This "hooks into" the JVM at a lower level than is possible through the APIs in the Java class libraries.

And, before you ask:

1. I doubt that JVMTI is available on a real Android device.  (I don't know if there is an equivalent.)
2. A Java application using JVMTI to control its own threads would be a really bad idea.  Think about the reasons that `Thread.stop` and friends were deprecated, and multiply by 10.